# Pass String to method via CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

I would like to ask, is it possible to **pass string** value from view (xaml) to property in ViewModel?

I have Two tabs. First is "Process" and the second is "Non-Process". Depends on that string value RelayCommand will execute and fire method with DispatcherTimer (if Process then Dispatcher1, if Non-Process then Dispatcher2).

xaml:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown" >
       <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EmployeeViewM.MeasurementEndExecution}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Can I use **CommandParameter** and **CommandParameterValue** to pass that **string** to the property?

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: Before asking if you can, did you try it? *Of course* you can use `CommandParameter`, and it haven't to be a `string`, it can be anything you want and it can bind to any property you want. If you have 2 windows, in the first you can pass the string "process" and in the second "non-process". The method that the command raises has a parameter of type `object`, and it is exactly the parameter that the window passes to the VM.

Comment: What _did_ you try? What happened? How was that different from what you wanted? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do, along with a precise description of what _specific_ problem you are having getting the code to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, like below:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown" >
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EmployeeViewM.MeasurementEndExecution}" CommandParameter="Process"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And/OR

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown" >
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EmployeeViewM.MeasurementEndExecution}" CommandParameter="Non-Process"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Hopefully your `RelayCommand` (or `ICommand` implementation) is already accepting `CommandParameter`. Like below.

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members


    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Comment: I have 3 questions. 1. Why are we throwing `ArgumentNullException` if (if I understand correctly) we're calling this constructor from another that defaults `execute` to null? 2. What is `CommandManager` for? 3. If we were nitpicky, it would be better to create two separate classes for with and without Predicate, right?

Comment: @Whazz Your concerns are thoughful but I just picked the basic definition of the RelayCommand from MSDN as the emphasis was on the ability to pass the values to the command in ViewModel. Not on the usefulness of Command design.